# Converting UTC to local time in android - queries

Tags: android, sqlite

For an android application, I store the date corresponding to an event in UTC format in a column in sqlite db. The UTC time will include up to milli seconds.When this time occur in user's handset, if the user has selected that particular event in the row(from app),alarm need to go on.

Upon selecting an event, I plan to fetch the UTC time from db and get this converted to user's local time in the handset and do the needful to set the alarm. Two questions:

1) Is this the correct approach?

2) What should be the data type of the date column which contains up to milli seconds. I need to store the UTC format using a data type with which the conversion to user's local time can be done easily without much of coding.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a correct approach.
   Other approaches would work, too.
2. See the [supported date/time datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).
   Both ISO8601 strings or Julian day numbers would work.